# .NET - MongoDb delete subdocument from document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with a following data

```
{
  "_id": "4e3951905e746b3805000000",
  "Name": "John",
  "Surname": "Mayer",
  "Comments": [
    {
      "_id": "4e3951965e746b8007000001",
      "content": "a"
    }
  ]
}
```

for instance i want to del a subdocument with id 4e3951965e746b8007000001 So this subdocument should be deleted

This my csharp code

```
public static void UpdateContentById(string id)
 {
    var defination = Builders<Client>.Update.PullFilter(p => p.Comments, c => c.Id == "4e3951965e746b8007000001");

    db.UpdateOne(p => p.Id == id, defination);
 }
```

That's the result I was expecting.

```
{
   "_id": "4e3951905e746b3805000000",
   "Name": "John",
   "Surname": "Mayer"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the field completely or just the embedded document and leave the field as an empty array?

Comment: if the last element is deleted,remove the field completely

Comment: is it a problem empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the last element from an array, array field is not deleted by itself. Usually it's a desirable behavior. If you have a model like this:

```
public class Client
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

`Comments` field will be deserialized as empty list. Unlike the case when `Comments` field is missing in the database document, in this case `Comments` property will be left as `null`. This will require additional checks for `null` in application logic or could cause `NullReferenceException`. Unless you initialize the list when object is constructed:

```
public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
```

Now `Comments` will be set as empty list even if the property is missing in the document. However that is exactly the same as if `Comments` array in the document was just left empty.

So I don't see much sense in deleting empty array fields. However if you want this behavior for some reason, you should do it by yourself with another update after element pull:

```
db.UpdateOne(p => p.Id == id, defination);
db.UpdateOne(p => p.Id == id && !p.Comments.Any(), Builders<Client>.Update.Unset(p => p.Comments));
```